# javascript about form.elements

Tags: javascript, forms

I am a JavaScript newbie and `form.elements` is making me confused. I have a demo like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function js() {
    var myform = document.forms[0];
    alert(myform.elements.length);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="js()">
  <form>
    <fieldset> this is a demo:
      <p> this is a p element</p>
      <label> this is a label element </label><br/>
      <input type="text" value="abc"/>
      <button type="button">click me</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Why does this return 3 elements instead of 5? I think the answer should be 5 elements (`fieldset`, `p`, `label`, `input` and `button`), because W3Schools states that "**`form.elements` returns a collection of all elements in a form**", but the browser tells me there's only 3 elements. Why?

Comment: Loop over the returned elements and see what is actually thought as an form element.

Comment: try to print the elemt array on console to see what eleemnt's does it return
console.log(myform.elements)

Comment: I think it returns only form elements. In this case fieldset, input and button. p and label are not form elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't return the `p` and `label` elements (or that `<br>` element you've got in there, either) as those aren't *listed* form elements (see below).

> The `HTMLFormElement.elements` property returns an `HTMLFormControlsCollection` (HTML 4 `HTMLCollection`) of all the form controls contained in the `FORM` element, with the exception of `input` elements which have a `type` attribute of image.
>
> — [MDN's Notes on HTMLFormElement.element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements).

The elements which `HTMLFormElements.elements` returns are collectivised in a subcategory of *form-associated elements* known as [*listed elements*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed) in the HTML specification:

> ***Listed elements***
>   Denotes elements that are listed in the `form.elements` and `fieldset.elements` APIs.
>
> > `button`, `fieldset`, `input`, `keygen`, `object`, `output`, `select`, `textarea`

Comment: Any chance to know why MDN includes and `label` element in [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms) but it won't return from `document.forms[0]` but `fieldset` will?

Comment: thinks, I get it. @James Donnelly

Answer (score 1):

In your code, only following are the [form elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#See_also)

```
[fieldset, input, button]
```

these are the names of possible form elements

```
<button>, <fieldset>, <input>, <output>, <progress>, <select>, <textarea>.
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy5vob8f/)

I have put a console log to show which those form elements are

```
function js() {
    var myform = document.forms[0];
    console.log( myform.elements );
  }
```

Comment: As it seems in MDN doc includes and `label` but it won't return from `document.forms[0]`.

Comment: @AlexChar check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zy5vob8f/2/ I have removed which are not working

Answer (score 0):

This is because `p` and `label` are not form elements. We have the following form elements like

- input
- select
- textarea
- button
- datalist
- keygen
- output

Answer (score 0):

Your code show 3 elements as form elements `fieldset` (HTMLFieldSetElement), `input` (HTMLInputElement) & `button` (HTMLButtonElement) . `label` and `p` are not treated as form elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function js() {
    var myform = document.forms[0];
    alert.log(myform.elements.length);
for(var i=0;i<myform.elements.length;i++)
  {
   alert(myform.elements[i]);
  }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="js()">
  <form>
    <fieldset> this is a demo:
      <p> this is a p element</p>
      <label> this is a label element </label><br/>
      <input type="text" value="abc"/>
      <button type="button">click me</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `p` , `label` elements arent a form element so when you want to count the number of form element it give `3`

by the way if you want to know the following elements are a form elements:

```
<form>  Defines an HTML form for user input

<input> Defines an input control

<textarea>  Defines a multiline input control (text area)

<label> Defines a label for an <input> element

<fieldset>  Groups related elements in a form

<legend>    Defines a caption for a <fieldset> element

<select>    Defines a drop-down list

<optgroup>  Defines a group of related options in a drop-down list

<option>    Defines an option in a drop-down list

<button>    Defines a clickable button

<datalist>  Specifies a list of pre-defined options for input controls

<keygen>    Defines a key-pair generator field (for forms)

<output>    Defines the result of a calculation
```